# Custom table with neutral tag between rows

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I created the following custom table:

http://jsfiddle.net/pg92nzh2/ (live example)

```
<div class="table-custom">
  <div class="table-heading">
    <div class="table-cell">title 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">title 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">title 3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">title 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">test 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">test 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">test 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works great but I would like to be able to put a tag between rows (div, span or whatever) that won't affect the behavior of my table (the final goal is to use ng-repeat to this tag so I can have modular tables). Here is an example of what I would like to do: http://jsfiddle.net/gzdrz9mr/

I would like to put this tag preferably wherever I want without affecting anything...

Comment: I dont understand. What's wrong with doing that now? Your table loses the every-other background color?

Comment: oh you want to wrap the table row without effecting anything?

Comment: Have you tried `display: table-row-group;` ?  [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/gzdrz9mr/1/)

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper  The table-row-group looks great but I lose the odd/even background color... Oh and is there a way to create subsubrows (example here jsfiddle.net/8ypsxhLp ) and by extension subsub....rows?

Comment: @jmore009 exactly, look at TheIronDeveloper comment and my comments, we are on the good track!

Comment: In that case, you need to change your :nth-child selectors to something else. Here is an example using `.table-custom .table-stripe:nth-child` [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/gzdrz9mr/4/)

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper I see, thanks!  And what about the subsub...rows?

Comment: So the way :nth-child works is it groups sibling elements that match that selector.  If you add the `table-stripe` class on a group of elements that are next to eachother, they will stripe for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68012/discussion-between-ncohen-and-theirondeveloper).